# Constructor progressDialog is undefined error

Tags: android, progress-bar

I want to show the progress bar when image is clicked, which plays audio and stop the progress bar when video is ready to play or starts playing.

Below is the xml code for both image and progress bar

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_play"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/buttonplayicon" />

     <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/audio_progressbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
     </ProgressBar>
```

`onClick()` of image I am calling function **audioPlayer**

```
public void audioPlayer(String path) throws IllegalArgumentException, SecurityException, IllegalStateException, IOException{

            MediaPlayer mp ;
            mp = new MediaPlayer();

            mp.setDataSource("SERVER_PATH/xyz");
            //mp.prepare();

            mp.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener(){

                @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.start();
                    }
                });
            mp.prepareAsync();

             ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
         dialog.setMessage("Downloading Music :) ");

         dialog.dismiss();


        }
```

while seting the visibility of progress bar to invisible I get error **"Contructor progressDialog  is undefined"**
anyone knows how to fix this?

**EDIT 1**

Log-cat error :

```
06-16 17:10:30.474: I/SurfaceTextureClient(13164): [0x50baf5f0] frames:177, duration:3.011000, fps:58.766132
06-16 17:10:33.475: I/SurfaceTextureClient(13164): [0x50baf5f0] frames:178, duration:3.001000, fps:59.307468
06-16 17:10:36.475: I/SurfaceTextureClient(13164): [0x50baf5f0] frames:178, duration:3.000000, fps:59.328789
06-16 17:10:39.476: I/SurfaceTextureClient(13164): [0x50baf5f0] frames:177, duration:3.000000, fps:58.982605
06-16 17:10:42.482: I/SurfaceTextureClient(13164): [0x50baf5f0] frames:179, duration:3.006000, fps:59.537594
06-16 17:10:45.483: I/SurfaceTextureClient(13164): [0x50baf5f0] frames:177, duration:3.000000, fps:58.982025
06-16 17:10:48.497: I/SurfaceTextureClient(13164): [0x50baf5f0] frames:176, duration:3.013000, fps:58.400032
06-16 17:10:50.244: V/Provider/Setting(13164): invalidate [system]: current 2 != cached 0
06-16 17:10:50.248: V/Provider/Setting(13164): from db cache, name = sound_effects_enabled value = 0
06-16 17:10:50.249: D/AndroidRuntime(13164): Shutting down VM
06-16 17:10:50.249: W/dalvikvm(13164): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x411c0908)
06-16 17:10:50.253: E/AndroidRuntime(13164): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-16 17:10:50.253: E/AndroidRuntime(13164): java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
06-16 17:10:50.253: E/AndroidRuntime(13164):    Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method findViewById(int) from the type Activity
06-16 17:10:50.253: E/AndroidRuntime(13164):    at com.example.paly_btn_imgapp.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment.audioPlayer(MainActivity.java:131)
06-16 17:10:50.253: E/AndroidRuntime(13164):    at com.example.paly_btn_imgapp.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:82)
06-16 17:10:50.253: E/AndroidRuntime(13164):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4091)
06-16 17:10:50.253: E/AndroidRuntime(13164):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17072)
06-16 17:10:50.253: E/AndroidRuntime(13164):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
06-16 17:10:50.253: E/AndroidRuntime(13164):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-16 17:10:50.253: E/AndroidRuntime(13164):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
06-16 17:10:50.253: E/AndroidRuntime(13164):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
06-16 17:10:50.253: E/AndroidRuntime(13164):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-16 17:10:50.253: E/AndroidRuntime(13164):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-16 17:10:50.253: E/AndroidRuntime(13164):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
06-16 17:10:50.253: E/AndroidRuntime(13164):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
06-16 17:10:50.253: E/AndroidRuntime(13164):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**EDIT 2**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);

        ImageView im = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.img_play);



        im.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {



            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                try {
                //showProgressbar();    
                audioPlayer("SERVER_PATH/xyz.mp3");
                //  prepareMediaPlayer();
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SecurityException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });


        return rootView;
    }

    public void audioPlayer(String path) throws IllegalArgumentException, SecurityException, IllegalStateException, IOException{

        MediaPlayer mp ;
        mp = new MediaPlayer();

        mp.setDataSource("SERVER_PATH");
        //mp.prepare();

        mp.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener(){

            @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.start();
                }
            });
        mp.prepareAsync();

         ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
         dialog.setMessage("Downloading Music :) ");

         dialog.dismiss();

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace

Comment: The issue is on your MainActivity.java line :131 please post that code

Comment: On line 131 its dialog.dismiss();

Comment: No, i mean post the whole code from onCreate()

Comment: just added the code. Please have a look

Comment: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method findViewById(int) from the type Activity...The above piece of code is fine...problem is somewhere else in your MainActivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `ImageView im = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.img_play);` is producing the error try replacing it with

```
ImageView im = (ImageView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.img_play);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   //  Try this 

   public class MyProgressDialog extends Dialog {

  public MyProgressDialog(Context context) {

    super(context, R.style.Theme_CustomDialog_new);
    super.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.row_progress);
    this.setCancelable(false);
    this.show();

 }
  }


 //use this

 MyProgressDialog pDialog = new MyProgressDialog("Your Activity Name");
 pDialog.setCancelable(false);
 pDialog.show();

//dismiss like

if (pDialog != null)
{
   pDialog.dismiss();
}
```